# Converting TIFF to PDF via Windows command line

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ocr

I'm looking for a *free* way to create a large batch of tif files (10-20k) into PDF files, ideally with OCR too.

It needs to be callable from the command line in windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [XnView application](http://www.xnview.com/). It's got command line too.

Another alternative might be [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/).

Answer (score 4):

You can try [LibTiff.Net](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff) library for this. It comes with tiff2pdf utility that can be used to create PDF from TIFF files. Unfortunately, there is no support for OCR.

Disclaimer: I am one of the maintainers of the library.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use GhostScript to create a PDF from a Tiff via commandline. Or build your own commandline app using iTextSharp to create PDF files.

Not sure about OCRing tho...