# converting multiple tiff to single pdf in .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf-generation, tiff

I am using MVC 4 to build a web application.  I need to implement a functionality that will convert multiple Tiff images to a single PDF.

I have looked at things like ItextSharp.

Has anyone else done something like this before?  what tools/libraries have you used?

Thanks

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152451/converting-tiff-to-pdf-via-windows-command-line?rq=1) asks a very similar questions and has some good answers, specifically, [LibTiff.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5154969/461958) looks very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I am  big fan of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). Though it can do so much more than file conversion, it does do that pretty  well.  Use the .NET library [Magick.NET](https://magick.codeplex.com/)

Here is some sample code to [convert to PDF](https://magick.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Convert%20PDF&referringTitle=Documentation)

To test using the command line tool, here is how it's done ([from ImageMagick forum](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14049)):

> convert Gears.tif -density 72 Gears.pdf

Comment: hi the sample page contains converting PDF to multiple images.  I want to go the other way, multiple images to one tiff

Comment: @user2206329 your questions states multiple tiff to single PDF. In any case ImageMagick will pretty much convert anything into anything. In the examples it has: PDF to multiple images and PDF from multiple images.