# how to use ItextSharp to convert multiple tif images to one PDF

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, itext

I am building an MVC 4 application in C#.  I have multiple tif images (not a multipage tif document) that I need to convert to a single PDF document (multi-page)

does anyone have any samples etc?

Comment: What have you tried? (Because you're asking for something that is very well documented.)

Comment: i have tried this http://atashbahar.com/post/Converting-Multipage-TIFF-image-to-PDF.aspx, but nothing about mutiple tifs anywhere.  Please point me to the very well documented site about converting multiple tifs to a single pdf

Comment: In other words: you are saying that you're unable to create a loop that executes the code snippet you found for a series of images?

Comment: yes..... thats exactly what I am saying

Comment: So your question isn't about iTextSharp, but about elementary programming. You should adjust your question.

Comment: it is about ITextSharp... seriously I am not asking how to create a loop... read the question

Comment: I guess the best answer to such a remark would be: *Read the manual!* http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251946/duplicate-questions-versus-rtfm

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting multiple tiff to single pdf in .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331118/converting-multiple-tiff-to-single-pdf-in-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that `sourcedir` is the directory where `.tif` the images reside, then you need:

```
Image image;
Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.tif");
foreach (string fileName in fileEntries) {
    image = Image.GetInstance(filename);
    image.ScaleToFit(595, 842);
    image.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
    document.Add(image);
    document.NewPage();
}
```

In this snippet, I assume that the size of your page is A4 (595, 842). I also add the image in the lower-left corner. You may want to center the image and/or resize the pages.